# esample Equivalent in R (using nlme)?

Tags: lme4-nlme, panel-data

I am trying to pull the estimation sample used in my model. Sadly, I cannot share the data or the detailed makeup of the data as I am working in a cloud system for an online research database. But I don't think you really need to know the data for this question.
Basic summary stats: I have 5,306 people with longitudinal (panel) observations of a continuous outcome. The data spans 6 years so you can imagine it's a large dataset (like 4mil obs.).
This is my model, using the `nlme` package (it's a curvilinear model):

`m42 <- lme(hr_diff ~ wave_n + I(wave_n^2) + race_cat*I(wave_n^2) + gender + sexual + age_baseline + education + income + emp_status + bmi_f + as.factor(heart_condition) + as.factor(smoking_status) + alcohol_use + sb_use,  random = ~ 1 | person_id, data = df_new, method = "ML",   control = lmeControl(maxIter = 1000))`

There are no missing values!

[image: lme_output_summary]

But, as I said the dataset I used `df_new` has 5306 unique participants, and the summary of this model shows me the degrees of freedom as 5279. I want to pull those unique 5279 people so I can perform secondary analyses on that sample. The PI on this project uses Stata and said Stata has an `esample` code that pulls that estimation. I am not sure if there is a direct translation in R for an `nlme` model. I tried subsetting based on `person_id` (the identifier) but I keep pulling longitudinal datasets with multiple rows of observations. And I tried to use:

`sample_used <- m42$subset`
but I get an output of 0.

If I try:
`sample_used <- m42@frame`

I get this error:
`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): trying to get slot "frame" from an object (class "lme") that is not an S4 object  Traceback:`

Does anyone have any idea what I can do or is there no way to pull the sample from this model?

Comment: what exactly does the model summary say? Is 5279 what it states under "number of observations"? The `DF` column in the coefficient table is not the same as the number of participants ... `fitted_model$data` should extract the data component ...